# Is there risk in assigning the output of stringByAppendingString to the same instance?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is there risk in assigning the output of `-[NSString stringByAppendingString]` to the same instance? I remember running into issue with this but don't recall the exact situation.

```
string = [string stringByAppendString:@"more string"];
```

Comment: It's only a potential memory issue under MRC.

Answer (score 2):

Before your line executes, `string` is a pointer to one `NSString` instance. Afterward, `string` points to a different instance. You haven't changed the original, you just don't have a pointer to it anymore.

If you're using ARC (the default), or the original string was autoreleased or is a string literal constant, there's no further cleanup to worry about.